# Записывая данные в DB Accses, получаю исключение "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO"

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, исключения, access

Код для записи данных в БД

```
public override void Execute()
    {
        OleDbConnection sqlConnection = new OleDbConnection(StrConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        string cmdText = $"INSERT INTO Users (Login, Password, Function, FullName) VALUES ('" + Login + "', '" + Password + "', '"+ Position +"' , '"+ FullName +"')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // В это строке возникает исключение
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

[image: Таблица БД в которую нужно внести данные]

Comment: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO" - и все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string cmdText = $"INSERT INTO Users ([Login], [Password], [Function], [FullName]) ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, РАБОТАЕТ!